# Configuring NGINX to only allow a unique ip to do 5 POST requests a day

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a website that allows users to convert their zipcode to their street address, city, and some other info. This is a website that is intended for end users and not for companies. However, since last week, I am getting lots of requests (1000 a day or so) from a couple of IPs and after some debugging it seems that they are (ab)using my website for commercial purposes.

I want my NGINX to only allow 5 POST requests from a unique IP per day, unless the requests are from my own IPs (office and home IPs). I am okay with GET requests having no limit. Also, I only want this to be applicable on this specific vhost and not my entire nginx config. How should i proceed? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't allow rate limits slower than 1 request per minute. However, you could use [this custom version of nginx](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build) that seems to have the feature you want. With it, you could do something like:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zonepost:10m rate=1r/d; # limit to 1 request per day
```

Then in your locations you could use an `if` to check if the request method is `get` or `post` and apply the `limit_req` accordingly. For example, you could have a second less restrictive zone and configure it like so:

```php
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zonepost:10m rate=5r/d; # limit 5 per day
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zoneget:10m rate=10r/s; # limit 10 per sec

server {
    location / {
         # Select the right zone (limit)
               if( $request_method = get ) {
                  set $zone "zoneget";
               }
               if( $request_method = post ) {
                  set $zone "zonepost";
               }
               limit_req zone=$zone;
         # Do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Refer to [this page on nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) for a manual.